# How to avoid html entities like &#8211; in JSON data in WP REST API?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, html-encode, wordpress-plugin-creation

In wordpress site while fetching JSON data using WP REST API how to decode &#8211, &#8220, etc.
Some latest android webview fails to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your theme `functions.php` , it acts as a middleware to resolve entities before serving it to the API.

```
function fix_decode_rest_api($response, $post, $request) {

    if (isset($post)) {
        
        $decodedTitle = html_entity_decode($post->post_title);
        $response->data['title']['rendered'] = $decodedTitle;
 
        
        $decodedPostTitle = html_entity_decode($response->data['title']['rendered']);
        $response->data['title']['rendered'] = $decodedPostTitle;
    }
    return $response;
}
add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'fix_decode_rest_api', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Why do you decode the same key value `rendered` twice?

Answer (score 0):

Just decode the string in the request instead of calling the database all over again. You already have the content to decode in $response

```
$response->data['title']['rendered'] = html_entity_decode($response->data['title']['rendered']);
```